# 100% width for image in modal dialog

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, modal-dialog, image-display

I want the image in my modal dialog to be width:100%, but do not know how to do it.

I'm using this code (thank you [Mohamed El-Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/mohamed-el-qassas-mvp)):

```
<script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Image',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
width: 800,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://url');"><img src="xxx.png"></a>
```

My 'openDialog' points to an URL and displays an image.
My 'img src' is a thumbnail image.

All is working, but my image is too big for the modal size - I want the image to shrink-to-fit or to be of width:100%, no matter the real size of the image.

[image: screenshot of image too big for modal dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option to `shrink to fit` the inside contents in the `Modal Popup dialog` in SharePoint.

Instead, try to use [fancy box jquery modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194066/fancybox-resize-to-fit-content-without-title)

---

But if you need to work with SharePoint Modal, I think the auto size width will be suitable for you!

Just remove the `width` option `width: 800` in the code!

```
<script>
function openDialog(pageUrl) {
var options = {
url: pageUrl,
title: 'Image',
allowMaximize: false,
showClose: true,
height: 500
};
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="openDialog('http://url');"><img src="xxx.png"></a>
```

**Output**

[image]

Check also at [open a SharePoint link via SharePoint Modal](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/08/13/open-link-via-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add

```
width:100% !important;
```

To the img via css

Comment: Thanks, but that will change all images. It does not seem to have a class the way it is rendered, so I think the best is to get the size done inside the modal code...